# Issues of setting a custom seekbar on xamarin android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
<SeekBar
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar"
...
```

In drawable/seekbar.xml

```html
<layer-list  
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/seekbg" />  
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">  
        <clip>  
            <shape>  
               <corners android:radius="2.0dip" />  
               <gradient android:startColor="#80ffd300" android:endColor="#a0ffcb00" android:angle="270.0" android:centerY="0.75" android:centerColor="#80ffb600" />  
            </shape>  
        </clip>  
    </item>  
   <item android:id="@android:id/progress">  
       <clip android:drawable="@drawable/seek" />  
   </item>  
</layer-list>
```

No resource found that matches the given name (at 'progressDrawable' with value '@drawable/seekbar').

How to solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The XML all looks correct, so it would seem that for some reason your Resource.designer.cs file has not been updated to include the seekbar drawable.

Perhaps try cleaning and rebuilding your project, even deleting the bin and obj folders to make sure there is no cached data that may be messing things up.